# Как получить числа без скобок функцией fetchall()?

Tags: python, sqlite

Функция fetchall() выводит значения в след формате: `[(717229086,), (741805325,)]` 
Мне нужно получить только числа через запятую. Как?

Comment: Обратитесь к первому элементу каждого кортежа, через `list comprehenshion`, например.

Comment: Вам стоит разобраться в типах данных, с которыми вы работаете. В памяти компьютера нет никаких скобочек и запятых — это **список кортежей**, а каждый кортеж состоит из одного элемента — числа (в виде аннотации это можно записать как `list[tuple[int]]`). А то, что вы хотите получить, это **список чисел** (или `list[int]`). А если вам даже квадратные скобочки не нужны, то значит вы хотите получить **строку**, отформатированную в нужном вам формате